# How to notify web server to response to a long-polling?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

We have a web server, a client application and an server application reacting with it. The following picture describes the structure.

[image]

The system works like this: The user changes some thing on the Client Application, for example change the title of a book. It will sends a TCP/IP package to the Server Application. My expect result is that the book title displayed in web browser should always be changed automatically. As I know, the web browser should keep a Long-Polling request with web server. My question is that how can the server application notify Web server about the changes? What kind of technology should I use?

All the applications are written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use JMS queue. When web browser turns to server to perform long polling it should arrive to servlet that connects to queue and calls blocking `receive()` method. 
When client application notifies server app. appropriate message should be sent into the queue. At this moment the blocking `receive()` will return and servlet will send update message to web browser and go back to blocking `receive()` until the next notfication will be sent.

To avoid mismatch between sessions you can either use dynamic queues or (better) one queue with selector that can be equal to current session ID.

The messages can be sent to web client serialized using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

"Comet" is designed for long-polling http request. See:  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)  for detail.
There are some implements of Comet, eg: Nginx + mod_push, your Server-app send a http to the Nginx to push a msg, then send to browser by nginx.